# MySQL select top 10 results prepared statement

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have inserted some data into a database and it consists of a few scores.

I need to:

Sort the scores out and extract the top 10 results including name, ID and username

My insert statement:

```
    // Insert example
    String sql = "insert into ratings (id, username, score, name) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";

    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setLong(1, userID);
    preparedStatement.setString(2, username);
    preparedStatement.setString(3, score);
    preparedStatement.setString(4, name);

    preparedStatement.execute();
```

Comment: Do you know anything about SQL?  This is a basic `select` with `order by`.

Comment: So, you need ordering, and taking the top values. Do you know how to do the ordering part?

Comment: a good tutorial cannot be replaced by SO

Comment: Is there any way for me to prevent repeated results from the same user name? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
select id, username, score, name from ratings order by score desc limit 10
```

Comment: Is there any way for me to prevent repeated results from the same user name?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following:

```
SELECT Id, Username, Score, Name FROM RATINGS ORDER BY SCORE DESC LIMIT 10.
```

Refer to the [MySQL Documentation for Select Clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
String sql = "insert into ratings (id, username, score, name) values (?, ?, ?, ?) order by score desc limit 10";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setLong(1, userID);
preparedStatement.setString(2, username);
preparedStatement.setString(3, score);
preparedStatement.setString(4, name);

preparedStatement.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the next?:

```
  SELECT id, username, score, name 
    FROM ratings 
ORDER BY SCORE DESC 
   LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM RATINGS ORDER BY SCORE DESC LIMIT 10
```

You need the `ORDER BY` to sort, then you need
`DESC` to sort it in a descending order and finally
`LIMIT 10` is for having only 10 results.